# Download file using wget

Tags: python, download, wget

I need to download fits files from a webpage. I'm doing this using `-i` wget options: I store the download file in a `list.txt` file which contains URL1, URL2... and then

```
$ wget -i list.txt
```

Do you know if there is the possibility to do the same thing using a Python script?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your file contains one URL per line, you can do this:

```
import urllib2
with open('list.txt') as my_list:
    for line in my_list:
        response = urllib2.urlopen(line)
        html = response.read()
        # now process the page's source
```

Comment: Ok it seems it works. But what if the website is protected by username and password? 
The same script in this case returns 
     urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Authorization Required
How can I solve the problem?

Comment: See the example at http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/authentication.shtml#doing-it-properly

Answer (score 1):

If you get SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED:

```
import wget
import ssl

ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
with open('list.txt') as my_list:
    for url in my_list:
        wget.download(url)
```

Using the OS library:

```
import os

with open('list.txt') as my_list:
    for url in my_list:
        os.system('wget ' + url)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('list.txt') as my_list:
    for url in my_list:
        wget.download(url)
```