# Download file with wget, and save file with original name

Tags: python, download, wget

I have a URL like this:

> "https://..../get_file.asp?sno=DEJENLFEBI"

When i try to download it with wget, I receive a file with name like:

> "get_file.asp?sno=DEJENLFEBI"

But, if i go to this url in my browser, I can save it with its normal name

> "DIR603A1_FW100CNB22.bin"

How can I download this file by url, and get it sours name?

Comment: Duplicate on other stack exchange site: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/453465/wget-how-to-download-a-served-file-keeping-its-name

Comment: I think with the -O parameter you can define the output name. but here seems to be another problem, is the "get_file.asp?sno=DEJENLFEBI" file the same size as the file you downloaded in browser?

Comment: @kurdy, yes, files are same..

Comment: Did the -O parameter work? I like this curl compatible cheatsheet cheat.sh. Just add what you want to know: cheat.sh/wget/. Did this solve your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Download file using wget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14894004/download-file-using-wget)